# Chrome app in window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to create chrome web app that will open in own window like Google Keep extension for chrome.
I made chrome web store package, but how to open it in self window instead of chrome browser ??

Comment: [`chrome.app.window`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html)?

Comment: maybe, do you have any example of usage??

Comment: Perhaps the simplest example is Google's Hello World app: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/samples.html#2b49c911de054ac4f0b17682b0d2bcc4. A background script listens for `app.runtime.onLaunched` and then opens a window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [packaged app](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) by

- Using a [manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest.html) with `{ 'app': { 'background': '...' } ...`.
- Add a `chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched` listener that calls [chrome.app.window.create](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html)

See the [hello-world sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/hello-world).